# Drawing video from plug-in to HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, vlc, quicktime

Through my research it seems clear to me that there isn't really a solution for playing a continuous h.264 video stream through the HTML5 video tag, and that a plug-in will be necessary to play the stream.

However, one thing I'm trying to accomplish is image/video manipulation via the HTML5 Canvas.  This is easily accomplished when using the native <img> or <video> tag.  I'm unclear if it's possible to pass the pixel data the canvas needs from a plug-in.  Is this possible?

I'm plug-in agnostic at this point.  Do any of VLC, Quicktime, Realplayer, Silverlight, Flash, or any other plug-in include an API that can be called to retrieve this snap-shot data?  Or alternatively, is there some other way of approaching this that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Why do you say: "...there isn't really a solution for playing a continuous h.264 video stream"?  What part of html5 video tag streaming does not meet your needs?

Comment: It's my understanding that you can't run a live stream via the video tag at present.  HTTP Live Streaming exists for iOS devices, but for everything else you need to use a plugin.  A day of searching the web led me to this conclusion, but if that's not the case I'd be very happy to hear it.